# Posting Checked table contents via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to post the values of a checked table i have populated from a database. I wont know how many rows there will be in the table as it is populated from the database and depends on how many bookings a user has done.

Here is a screenshot of the table:

[image]

And here is the code in the function that populates that table.

```
$details .= '<tr>
        <td class="checkbox-column"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" class="icheck-input" /></td>
        <td>'.$booking_reference.'</td>
        <td><input name="amount'.$i.'" value="'.$row["amount"].'"</td>
        <td>'.$strip.'</td>
        <td>'.$row['confirmed'].'</td>
        </tr>';

        $i++;
    }

    $details .= '</tbody></table><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submit_confirm()">Confirm</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="submit_deny()">Deny</button>      
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="submit_delete()">Delete</button>';
    return $details;
```

What i want to do is when the user checks the box then i want to post the information in the row / rows across to a php page called process.php then from there I know what to do but its the posting across that im struggling with.

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated. I hope the question makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: If you want to use JS, then you'd find it easier to assign a class to the table or rows and then iterate through them, then send the data via AJAX to the processing script. However, you might find it easier to handle the condition in the process (gives you a noscript backup too), but doing that would be easier if you had the form fields passed as arrays (put `[]` at the end of the field name) - then you merely iterate through those arrays only processing the text field if the value of the checkbox is set.

Comment: Basically u want to get the rows only of selected?

Comment: Do you need send information every time user clicked checbox or just after "Confirm" or "Delete" button was clicked?
And what data do you need on server? I think it should be something like id of selected rows, in that case you need add this ids in your html.

Comment: I only send the data once the confirm button is pressed. Then all the information - Ref num - points etc posted to a file called post.php where they will be used to update the database.